# How to find common elements at the same indices in two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists and I want to get the elements that are in both lists and at the same indices. For example:

```
l1 = [1,2,4,7,0,6]
l2 = [1,6,9,7,5]
```

I want:`[1,7]`

My attempt:

```
l3 = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] == l2[i]:
        l3.append(l1[i])
print(l3)
```

produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\d-ss\Desktop\t1.py", line 5, in <module>
    if l1[i] == l2[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `print([i for i, j in zip(l1, l2) if i==j])` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to zip the two lists so you can iterate through them simultaneously:

```
l1 = [1,2,4,7,0,6]
l2 = [1,6,9,7,5]
l3 = []
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    if i == j:
        l3.append(i)
print(l3)
```

Output:

```
[1, 7]
```

---

You can also turn it into a list comprehension:

```
l3 = [i for i, j in zip(l1, l2) if i==j]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
l1 = [1,2,4,7,0,6]
l2 = [1,6,9,7,5]
l3 = []
if len(l1)< len(l1):
    list_l = l1
else:
    list_l = l2
for i in range(len(list_l)):
    if l1[i] == l2[i]:
        l3.append(l1[i])
print(l3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a smaller list by using `len(l1 if len(l1)< len(l1)else l2`. So code will be like this:

```
l1 = [1,2,4,7,0,6]
l2 = [1,6,9,7,5]
l3 = []
for i in range(len(l1 if len(l1)< len(l1)else l2)):
    if l1[i] == l2[i]:
        l3.append(l1[i])
print(l3)
```

The output will be:

```
[1, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the index out of range in your code is due to the fact that `len(l1) != len(l2)`.

The zip method is a nice way to check multiple lists side by side.

```
l1 = [1,2,4,7,0,6]
l2 = [1,6,9,7,5]

l = [x[0] for x in zip(l1, l2) if x[0] == x[1]]
print(l)
```

Gives

```
[1, 7]
```